# AWS glue error in converting dynamic dataframe to spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue crawler to read some data from S3 into a table.
I would like to then use the AWS Glue jobs to do some transformations.  I am able to modify and run the script of a small file, but when I try to run it on larger data, I get the following error that seems to be complaining about converting Dynamic Frame to spark dataframe.  I am not even sure how to start debugging it.
I didn't see many posts on this here -- only about sparkDF->Dynamic frames.

````
No older events found for the selected filter. clear filter.

18:49:31
er$$anonfun$init$1.apply(GrokReader.scala:62) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:162) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$16.hasNext(Iterator.scala:599) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.GrokReader.hasNext(GrokReader.scala:117) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.TapeHadoopRecordReader.nextKeyValue(TapeHadoopRecordReader.scala:73) at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopR
er$$anonfun$init$1.apply(GrokReader.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:162)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$16.hasNext(Iterator.scala:599)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.GrokReader.hasNext(GrokReader.scala:117)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.TapeHadoopRecordReader.nextKeyValue(TapeHadoopRecordReader.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:462)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
2020-05-12 18:49:22,434 INFO  [Thread-9] scheduler.DAGScheduler (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Job 0 failed: fromRDD at DynamicFrame.scala:241, took 8327.404883 s
2020-05-12 18:49:22,450 WARN  [task-result-getter-1] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9983.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9986, ip-172-32-50-149.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 2): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,451 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 10000.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10003, ip-172-32-50-149.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 2): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,451 WARN  [task-result-getter-3] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9986.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9989, ip-172-32-50-149.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 2): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,451 WARN  [task-result-getter-0] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9985.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9988, ip-172-32-50-149.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 2): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,451 WARN  [task-result-getter-1] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9864.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9864, ip-172-32-62-222.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 5): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,454 INFO  [dispatcher-event-loop-3] storage.BlockManagerInfo (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Added broadcast_25_piece0 in memory on ip-172-32-56-53.us-west-2.compute.internal:34837 (size: 32.1 KB, free: 2.8 GB)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,455 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9900.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9900, ip-172-32-62-222.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 5): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,456 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9991.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9994, ip-172-32-56-53.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 4): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,456 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9949.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9949, ip-172-32-56-53.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 4): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,456 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9975.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9977, ip-172-32-62-222.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 5): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,456 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9995.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9998, ip-172-32-62-222.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 7): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,456 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 10001.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10004, ip-172-32-62-222.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 5): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,457 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9993.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9996, ip-172-32-62-222.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 7): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,457 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9939.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9939, ip-172-32-62-222.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 7): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,457 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9930.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9930, ip-172-32-62-222.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 7): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,457 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9998.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10001, ip-172-32-54-163.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 6): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,462 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9965.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9967, ip-172-32-56-53.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 1): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,463 WARN  [task-result-getter-3] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9934.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9934, ip-172-32-56-53.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 1): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,463 WARN  [task-result-getter-0] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9990.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9993, ip-172-32-56-53.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 1): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,464 WARN  [task-result-getter-1] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9992.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9995, ip-172-32-56-53.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 4): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,464 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9967.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9969, ip-172-32-56-53.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 4): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,464 WARN  [task-result-getter-0] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9982.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9985, ip-172-32-54-163.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 3): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,464 WARN  [task-result-getter-3] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9999.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10002, ip-172-32-54-163.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 3): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,464 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9984.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9987, ip-172-32-54-163.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 3): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,464 WARN  [task-result-getter-0] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9966.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9968, ip-172-32-54-163.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 3): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,467 WARN  [task-result-getter-3] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9996.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9999, ip-172-32-54-163.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 6): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,474 WARN  [task-result-getter-1] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9960.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9962, ip-172-32-54-163.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 6): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,474 WARN  [task-result-getter-2] scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(66)) - Lost task 9980.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9982, ip-172-32-54-163.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 6): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,514 INFO  [dispatcher-event-loop-0] yarn.YarnAllocator (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Driver requested a total number of 1 executor(s).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_2020-05-12-16-29-01.py", line 30, in <module>
    dns = datasource0.toDF()
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1589300850182_0001/container_1589300850182_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 147, in toDF
    return DataFrame(self._jdf.toDF(self.glue_ctx._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(scala_options)), self.glue_ctx)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1589300850182_0001/container_1589300850182_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1589300850182_0001/container_1589300850182_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1589300850182_0001/container_1589300850182_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o66.toDF.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 9929 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 9929.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 9983, ip-172-32-56-53.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 1): java.io.IOException: too many length or distance symbols
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.inflateBytesDirect(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.decompress(ZlibDecompressor.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.BufferedStream.read(DynamicRecordReader.scala:91)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.GrokReader$$anonfun$init$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(GrokReader.scala:68)
    at scala.util.control.Breaks.breakable(Breaks.scala:38)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.GrokReader$$anonfun$init$1.apply(GrokReader.scala:66)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.GrokReader$$anonfun$init$1.apply(GrokReader.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:162)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$16.hasNext(Iterator.scala:599)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.GrokReader.hasNext(GrokReader.scala:117)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.TapeHadoopRecordReader.nextKeyValue(TapeHadoopRecordReader.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:462)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2158)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$fold$1.apply(RDD.scala:1098)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1092)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1161)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.glue.util.SchemaUtils$.fromRDD(SchemaUtils.scala:72)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.recomputeSchema(DynamicFrame.scala:241)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.schema(DynamicFrame.scala:227)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.toDF(DynamicFrame.scala:290)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: too many length or distance symbols
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.inflateBytesDirect(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.decompress(ZlibDecompressor.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.BufferedStream.read(DynamicRecordReader.scala:91)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.GrokReader$$anonfun$init$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(GrokReader.scala:68)
    at scala.util.control.Breaks.breakable(Breaks.scala:38)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.GrokReader$$anonfun$init$1.apply(GrokReader.scala:66)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.GrokReader$$anonfun$init$1.apply(GrokReader.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:162)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$16.hasNext(Iterator.scala:599)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.GrokReader.hasNext(GrokReader.scala:117)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.TapeHadoopRecordReader.nextKeyValue(TapeHadoopRecordReader.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:462)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more

2020-05-12 18:49:22,587 ERROR [Driver] yarn.ApplicationMaster (Logging.scala:logError(70)) - User application exited with status 1
2020-05-12 18:49:22,588 INFO  [Driver] yarn.ApplicationMaster (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 1, (reason: User application exited with status 1)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,591 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] spark.SparkContext (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
2020-05-12 18:49:22,594 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] server.AbstractConnector (AbstractConnector.java:doStop(318)) - Stopped Spark@3a4d5cae{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:0}
2020-05-12 18:49:22,595 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] ui.SparkUI (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Stopped Spark web UI at http://ip-172-32-50-149.us-west-2.compute.internal:40355
2020-05-12 18:49:22,597 INFO  [dispatcher-event-loop-2] yarn.YarnAllocator (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Driver requested a total number of 0 executor(s).
2020-05-12 18:49:22,598 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] cluster.YarnClusterSchedulerBackend (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Shutting down all executors
2020-05-12 18:49:22,598 INFO  [dispatcher-event-loop-3] cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Asking each executor to shut down
2020-05-12 18:49:22,600 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] cluster.SchedulerExtensionServices (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Stopping SchedulerExtensionServices
(serviceOption=None,
 services=List(),
 started=false)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,604 INFO  [dispatcher-event-loop-3] spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
2020-05-12 18:49:22,616 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] memory.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - MemoryStore cleared
2020-05-12 18:49:22,616 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] storage.BlockManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - BlockManager stopped
2020-05-12 18:49:22,617 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] storage.BlockManagerMaster (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - BlockManagerMaster stopped
2020-05-12 18:49:22,618 INFO  [dispatcher-event-loop-2] scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
2020-05-12 18:49:22,621 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] spark.SparkContext (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Successfully stopped SparkContext
2020-05-12 18:49:22,623 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] yarn.ApplicationMaster (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: User application exited with status 1)
2020-05-12 18:49:22,631 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] impl.AMRMClientImpl (AMRMClientImpl.java:unregisterApplicationMaster(476)) - Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
2020-05-12 18:49:22,733 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] yarn.ApplicationMaster  ```
````

Comment: A more detailed stack trace could help identify where the issue is coming from. toDF() function is just calling or triggering the execution of whatever you have before this function. Are you running out memory? If you are running this in Glue Console, check the ETL data movement using metrics. More can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-profile-debug-straggler.html

Comment: @Eman.  Thank you!  I have updated the post.  It looks like there are a bunch of lost tasks.  Maybe due to my grok expression that I am using in the crawler.  I use this successfully with a shorter file.  Even if there are some differences in the data format in the bigger file, wouldn't glue just not read those lines instead of giving errors?

Comment: So it appears you are dealing with compressed files and the errors is thrown while decompressing one of your files. If these can easily be eliminated 1 by 1 try that. You are most likely dealing with corrupt files.

Comment: @Eman.  Thanks again!  
Is there a way to discard corrupted files?   In spark, I usually set a config parameter `ignoreCorruptFiles`.  Is there something similar that I might use here?

Comment: I do not have any file to test with but maybe you can try `connection_options = {"ignoreCorruptFiles":True}` or just reading as a data frame then use `fromDF()` to convert to dynamic frame

Comment: Seeing the same error with the `connection_options`.